# Why does my external display run at a lower refresh rate when MacBook's lid is closed?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm on a 16 inch MacBook Pro connected to an [LG 4k monitor](https://www.lg.com/in/monitors/lg-27UL500-W) connected via a USB-C to DisplayPort cable.

The display runs perfectly fine at 4k at 60 Hz refresh rate when the laptop's lid is open. However, as soon as I close the lid, the display switches to 4k at 30 Hz refresh rate.

What's the reason for this switch to lower refresh rate and how can I keep it running at 60 Hz?

Comment: @Tetsujin I've experienced it with browsers, IDEs, text editors etc. A spreadsheet may not  need 60 fps but it sure as hell looks smoother and less fatiguing to the eye than 30fps.

Comment: @Tetsujin I meant refresh rate, not fps. My bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190601/rmbp-outputs-4k60hz-only-when-lid-open